# Node.js - How to use a mysql query done in server/app.js on an javascript block

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

How do i use a mysql query inside a leaflet map(javascript). I get the querys just fine but dont now how to export the into the map itself.

I do the query on server.js like this:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'xxx',
user: 'admin',
password: 'xxx',
database: 'xxx'
});

connection.connect();
connection.query('SELECT latitud, longitud FROM  EstadoLocalizacion WHERE idLocal = (select max(idLocal) from EstadoLocalizacion)', (error, results) => {
if (error) {
    console.log(error);
}

let location2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
console.log(location2[0].latitud);
});
```

I want to use the results of the query(coordinates) to make a marker(let marker) at the bottom:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([19.4398316,-70.7430638], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(mymap);
let iconMarker = L.icon({
                    iconUrl: "/assets/img/greenCar.png",
                    iconSize: [45, 45],
                    iconAnchor: [15, 30]
                })
let marker = L.marker([19.4398316,-70.7430638], { icon: iconMarker }).addTo(mymap);

</script>
```

I've tried using handlebar partials but {{format}} does not work on the  block.

Comment:  **CHANGE YOUR CREDENTIALS ON AWS RIGHT NOW** and never, ever post credentials to Stack Overflow. You have just compromised your database.

Comment: Thats an old one, not in use but thanks! took note.

Comment: I tested it. It worked. **CHANGE IT NOW**. Do not do anything else until this is plugged.

Comment: @tadman Did you raise a custom flag to have the first revision removed?

Comment: @Scratte It's too late. The credentials are already out there. Changing the credentials fixes this problem. Paving it over *might*.

Comment: I erased it, was a test db. Wont happen again. Thanks!